# How can i customize the week number in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, week-number

Currently, the week number for the period of '2020-5-6' to '2020-5-19' is 20 and 21.
How do I customise it so that the week number is 1 and 2 instead, and also have the subsequent periods change accordingly.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2020-5-6', '2020-5-19')})
df['Period'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W-TUE')
df['Week_Number'] = df['Period'].dt.week
df.head()

print(df)
```

My output:

```
     Date                 Period             Week_Number
  0  2020-05-06  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           20
  1  2020-05-07  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           20
  2  2020-05-08  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           20
  3  2020-05-09  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           20
  ...
  11 2020-05-17  2020-05-13/2020-05-19           21
  12 2020-05-18  2020-05-13/2020-05-19           21
  13 2020-05-19  2020-05-13/2020-05-19           21
```

What I want:

```
     Date                 Period             Week_Number
  0  2020-05-06  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           1
  1  2020-05-07  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           1
  2  2020-05-08  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           1
  3  2020-05-09  2020-05-06/2020-05-12           1
  ...
  11 2020-05-17  2020-05-13/2020-05-19           2
  12 2020-05-18  2020-05-13/2020-05-19           2
  13 2020-05-19  2020-05-13/2020-05-19           2
```

Comment: Dy default you want that "2020-05-06  2020-05-06/2020-05-12" be week 1? Why don't you use "19" as a fixed number to subtract the week_numer if it will be the same in the year?
'df['Week_Number'] = df['Week_Number'] -19'

Comment: you could use `df['Week_Number'] = pd.factorize(df['Period'])[0]+1` if you want to start counting at date start